# ansible documentation of alternative use of deprecated ALLOW_WORLD_READABLE_TMPFILES

Tags: configuration, ansible, documentation

the deprecation warning discouraging the use of ALLOW_WORLD_READABLE_TMPFILES includes a reasoning:

```
ALLOW_WORLD_READABLE_TMPFILES option, moved to a per plugin approach that is more flexible. , use mostly the same config will work, but now controlled from the plugin itself and not using 
the general constant. instead.
```

however, i do not comprehend how to actually implement this alternative on a plugin basis, i couldn't find any further reference in the config documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#allow-world-readable-tmpfiles)

could anybody help me out here, or is it worth to raise a documentation issue on the github issue tracker?

Answer (score 1):

Valid problem with the docs documented in this issue: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/72264

...which also contains the answer to your question:

> Effectively, you will need to view the documentation related to the shell plugin you are using, likely sh, and substitute the configuration with the shell plugin specific config:
> https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/sh_shell.html#parameter-world_readable_temp